# Understanding how the "is" operator works int Python for result from function

Tags: python, function, syntax, operators, literals

For example we have this code.

```
x = 1
y = 1
print(x is y) # TRUE
print(id(x), id(y))
y = pow(10, 30, 10**30-1) # 1

print(type(y))
print(x, y, x is y) # FALSE
```

It`s return:

```
True
140516304938720 140516304938720
<class 'int'>
1 1 False
```

The last result is **False**. Please help me understand why this is happening? Result of function is 1, doesn`t it literal, which cach in python?

If we change to

```
y = pow(1, 10)
```

It will return "True".

Comment: As explained in the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) ```is``` compares object identity. ```==``` compares object equality. Two objects with the same value are equal, but they have different ```id(object)```. Small integers are not dynamically allocated, they are taken from a pool of preallocated objects. That's why small equal integers are always identical. That's an implementation detail that may change at any time.

Comment: Main point: Don't use `is` if you want to test for equality. That's what `==` is for.

Comment: What Matthias said. Use ```is``` in two cases: To test against None, as in ```if value is None``` or to check for "same object" instead of "equal object", which is rare but happens. If you know compiled languages like C, it is like comparing an address of a value instead of the value itself.

Comment: try printing out `id(y)` after you reassign it

Answer (score 0):

The **"is"** operator checks whether two items are the same object.
In your example it returns False because x is not the same object as y, even though they have the same content.

**for example:**

Here the x and y variables have the same content, but they are not the same object!

```py
x = ["apple", "banana"]
y = ["apple", "banana"]

print(x is y) #False
print(x == y) #True
```

To understand more, I suggest you check this link.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp

Answer (score -1):

x1 = 5

y1 = 5
x2 = 'Hello'

y2 = 'Hello'

x3 = [1,2,3]

y3 = [1,2,3]

print(x1 is not y1)  # prints False

print(x2 is y2)  # prints True

print(x3 is y3)  # prints False

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).